# Manipulate JSON Object Data After Iterating via For Each

Tags: json, python-3.x, foreach

Might be a dumb question or a small typo. I'm iterating through a JSON object I loaded in and my goal is to MTL some text deep inside. I'm iterating through a list of objects for a specified code, then I translate the text on a correct match. So Iterate through objects > Match Code > Translate Text

The problem is when I try to alter the object by replacing the text with the translated version, that data isn't changed in the returned data object.

```
def findMatch(data):
    # Search Events
    for event in data['events']:
        if (event is not None):
            pages = event['pages']
            for page in pages:
                lists = page['list']
                for list in lists:
                    if(list['code'] == 401):
                        for parameter in list['parameters']:
                            parameter = checkLine(parameter)

    return data
```

`checkLine(parameter)` will return a string of the text translated.

I'm guessing `parameter` isn't connected to the data object which is why it's not working but unsure how exactly it should be written out.

Also any suggestions on how to make this faster/more efficient are welcome.

Answer (score 0):

```py
for i, parameter in enumerate(list['parameters']):
    list['parameters'][i] = checkLine(parameter)
```

Does the trick.